# Trying to make a conditional checking shorter

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a conditional in Python 3 where I check a variable against a couple of numbers and I want to make the line as short as possible.

This line works:

```
while value != 1 and value != 5 and value != 10 and value != 25 and value != 50 and value != 100:
```

But I want to make it shorter, something like this:

```
    while value != 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100:
```

Is it possible or should I stick with the long line of code?

Comment: `while value not in (1, 5, ...):`?

Comment: it worked, thank you!